# JRuby + RVM + Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, rvm, jruby

Has anyone been able to install and use JRuby on Cygwin via RVM? If so, how? I'm able to install RVM and JRuby on Cygwin, but am unable to install any gems. The issue seems to be with path settings.

**PATH**

> /home/Ari/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4/bin:/home/Ari/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@global/bin:/home/Ari/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/bin:/home/Ari/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/home/Ari/bin

**Gem Env**

> RubyGems Environment:
>
> - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
> - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-05-16 patchlevel 392) [java]
> - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/Ari/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4
> - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Cygwin/home/Ari/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/bin/jruby.exe
> - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/Ari/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4/bin
> - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
>
>   - ruby
>   - universal-java-1.7
> - GEM PATHS:
>
>   - /home/Ari/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4
>   - /home/Ari/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4:/home/Ari/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4@global
> - GEM CONFIGURATION:
>
>   - :update_sources => true
>   - :verbose => true
>   - :benchmark => false
>   - :backtrace => false
>   - :bulk_threshold => 1000
>   - "install" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri --env-shebang"
>   - "update" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri --env-shebang"
> - REMOTE SOURCES:
>
>   - http://rubygems.org/

**Gem Installation Command & Error Message**

> jruby -S gem install jruby-lint
>
> Fetching: tins-0.8.2.gem (100%)
>   ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOENT)
>
> ```
> No such file or directory - C:/home/Ari/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4/cache/tins-0.8.2.gem
> ```

Comment: you need to provide more details, how do you install the gems, are you getting any errors? please include `echo $PATH; gem env`

Comment: @mpapis: I've updated my post to include path, gem env, installation command, and result details.

Comment: does the directory `C:/home/Ari/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4/cache` exist?

Comment: @mpapis: No, `C:/home/Ari/...` does not exist and therein lies the problem. `$HOME` is set to `/home/Ari`, where the root is `/cygdrive/c/Cygwin` or `C:/Cygwin`. But RVM prepends `C:/` rather than one of the two aforementioned root paths.

Comment: @mpapis: Note: `rvm use jruby` results in: `Using /home/Ari/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.4`. And so `which jruby` yields: `/home/Ari/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/bin/jruby `

Answer (score 0):

cygwin is not fully supported yet by RVM - there is a ticket to improve it https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1783 - please add your finding there so it can be improved.

Comment: Are you sure you want to add my findings there? That issue relates to installing rvm through an installation script. I successfully installed rvm 1.21.2 using the conventional bash command.

Comment: any information is important, what script was it? no matter of script RVM should behave correctly ... unless the script is broken - but then the script should be fixed.

Comment: The issue in the link you provided relates to an external rvm installation script -- i.e. a script NOT from RVM itself. I was clarifying if I should add my findings to this issue or create a new one.

Comment: you can open new one and mention the other